# opengl es 3.0 glsl multiplication crashes

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I'm currently working on a Bug in an image processing app under Android. On the devices that are available for me (Z5, Z3, Nexus 5x, OnePlus3, S6, Pixel C) it only happens on the Pixel C:

It seams like a simple floating point multiplication in a fragment shader causes the whole device to crash (not responding, needs reboot).

This is the shader source:

```
#version 300 es
#ifdef GL_ES
     precision mediump float;
#endif

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Uniforms
//
/**
 * Uniform sampler2D variable for accessing input texture.
 */
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;    ///< Input texture.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Varyings
//
/**
 * Varying variable representing the texture coordinates for sampling.
 * @minimum 0.0 0.0
 * @maximum 1.0 1.0
*/
in vec2 v_TexCoord;     ///< Input texture coordinates.
layout(location=0) out vec2 o_Color;

/**
 * Compute tangent flow at current fragment position.
 */
void main (void)
 {
    vec3 tensor = texture(u_Texture, v_TexCoord).xyz;
    float tensorXSubTensorY = tensor.x - tensor.y;
        vec2 lengthTensor = vec2(tensorXSubTensorY, tensor.z+tensor.z);
        /*********************************************/
        /*************BELOW CAUSES CRASH**************/
        float value = lengthTensor.x*lengthTensor.x;
         //float val2 = lengthTensor.y*lengthTensor.y;
        float lambda1 = 0.5 * (tensorXSubTensorY - value);

        vec2 tangent = vec2(lambda1, tensor.z);

    o_Color = (length(tangent) > 0.0) ? normalize(tangent) : vec2(0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The texture used is a Half-Float RGBA16F texture. Setting the value to e.g. 2.0f doesn't crash the device.

Is there any reason, why this line could be problematic?

Comment: Maybe that's because you're multiplying `lengthTensor.x` by itself? It should, of course, work fine but that could be a bug in device's OpenGL ES implementation.

Comment: It seems unusual that o_Color is a vec2. Does changing it to a vec4 make any difference.

Comment: I can test this next time i have access to the device (wednesday).
The last thing I found out was, that changing the float precision from mediump to highp (line 3) fixes the issue